# Is “stober” a kohen’s name?

Tags: kohen-priest

Is the name “Stober” a Kohen’s name?  Thank you for taking the time to answer this question I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Lisa. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Also please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Please note that there are Kohanim not called Mr. Kohen, and alternatively there are people called "Kahn", "Kohen" etc. who are not Kohanim. You cannot trust names to tell you whether someone is a Kohren or not. I suspect this question is not really answerable and might get closed but please don't let this deter from asking or answering other questions

Comment: This question might also be better suited for [Genealogy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/). Maybe you could get better answers if you try asking there.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/which-surnames-are-kohanims-and-why

Answer (score 1):

I found [in ancestry.co.uk](https://www.ancestry.co.uk/name-origin?surname=stober)

**Stober Name Meaning**

North German (Stöber): variant of Stöver (see Stoever). German: nickname from Slavic stobor ‘fighter’. German (Stöber): from Middle High German stöuber ‘hunting dog’, possibly a metonymic occupational name for someone who bred or cared for hunting dogs or a nickname for someone who resembled one.

I found [in houseofnames.com](https://www.houseofnames.com/stober-family-crest)

**Stober History, Family Crest & Coats of Arms**

The Stober surname is derived from the Old English personal name Stubheard.

I found [in names.org](https://www.names.org/n/stober/about#associations)

**User Submitted Meanings**

```
A user from Colorado, United States says the name Stober is of German origin and means "Fighter".
```

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Kohenitic_surnames) on surnames for kohanim does not list Stober in its 36 names.

See also [Cohanim names other than Cohen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83571/cohanim-names-other-than-cohen)

and [Which surnames are Kohanim's and why?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/which-surnames-are-kohanims-and-why)

In summary there is no evidence that I could find that “Stober” is a Kohen’s name. But as we often say here “absence of evidence is not evidence of absence”.